# How to deal with multiple objects listening to motion_notify_events on the same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling

I'm using matplotlib :

Let's say I have an object A, which has two attributes B and C, and a method that draws a figure. Both B and C have methods doing some stuff on the figure on events 'motion_notify_event'.

I've notice that both methods do not work at the same time, and there appears to be conflict.

How does one deal with such case ?

So I've written a code that shows the problem a little bit better than the above explanation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import MultiCursor
from matplotlib.patches import Circle


class Event1(object):

    def __init__(self,axes):

        self.fig  = axes[0].figure
        self.axes = axes

        self.eid = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event',self.onmove)


    def onmove(self,event):
        for ax in self.axes:
            c = Circle((event.xdata,event.ydata),radius=0.05)
            ax.add_patch(c)
            ax.draw_artist(c)

        self.fig.canvas.blit(self.fig.bbox)



class plotclass(object):

    def __init__(self):

        pass

    def plotme(self):

        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(211)
        self.ax2 = self.fig.add_subplot(212)

        for ax in (self.ax1,self.ax2):
            ax.set_xlim((0,10))
            ax.set_ylim((0,10))

#       self.curs = MultiCursor(self.fig.canvas,(self.ax1,self.ax2))

        self.ev1 = Event1((self.ax1,self.ax2))

        self.fig.show()



def main():

    pc = plotclass()

    return pc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now in this code there are two stuff listening the motion_notify_event : the class Event1, which will draw circles at the cursor position, and the class 'plotclass', which creates the figure and draws cursors at the cursor position.

I have commented out the line self.curs = ..., and I see the circles as the mouse is moving, but if I uncomment it, I just see the cursors : why ? and how to see both?

Comment: It's probably because the `MultiCursor` object uses blitting and you're using it as well.  Both your class and `MultiCursor` restore the canvas to its initial state and blit over it.  Therefore, whichever one goes last is the only one that appears. A quick fix is to pass in `useblit=False` to multicursor, but that will slow it down.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on my comment above, it's not due to the multiple event handling, it's due to different stages of blitting overwriting each other.

Blitting typically works by restoring a saved, fully-rendered state and then drawing on top of it.

In your current code, you're blitting but not restoring the saved state, so you get a "trail" of circles (presumably this is what you want).

However, `MultiCursor` calls `fig.canvas.restore_region(...)` *before* drawing itself (otherwise you'd have a "trail" of lines). Therefore, it restores a saved "blank" figure over what you've just drawn.

If you want use multiple passes of blitting, they'll need to coordinate with each other.  There are a number of different ways to handle this, but they're overkill for most use cases. The quick fix is to pass in `useblit=False` to `MultiCursor`.  This will slow your rendering down, however.

Can you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to do? Do you just want a cursor with a circle in the mouse position? (If so, just subclass `MultiCursor`.)

Comment: The circles are just for the example. What I really want is the multicursor and drawing the rectangles as I showed earler in this other post http://bpaste.net/show/Fmkw75xZH3JFJbRi2qob/
So far, I get the same problem as with the circles, i.e. I see my multicursor but not the rectangles being dragged. Of course if I do useblit=False, I'll get back to the problem where drawing my rectangles for the 14 axes is way too slow to be usable. One workaround I was thinking would be to disable the MultiCursor somehow on the click event, i.e. when I  begin to drag my rectangles.

Comment: @Heimdall - That's probably easiest. You'll have to subclass `MultiCursor` to not only allow the disable/enable, but also to refresh its internal saved state of the canvas.  It's not too difficult, but it will be a bit verbose.

Comment: @Heimdall - Here's an example of how I'd do it based on your linked example.  I've also made several changes to your `Zones` class that should help performance (as well as several simplifications). https://gist.github.com/joferkington/7566594

Comment: thanks a lot! It's funny I had in the mean time implemented my own version of "synched cursor" with the same idea of boolean except I had added two new methods onpress() and onrelease() to set it to False or True, respectively. Then redefined the onmove() with the same check on that boolean.. but the cursors were always there... I suspect this is because the Parent class has associated 'motion_notify_event' to its own onmove() method, and because they don't store the id I can't disconnect it. Do you agree on that interpretation?